# HTML/CSS: How can I float the 'a href' elements to the left without them leaving the div element that they are inside in?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for demonstration:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a{
              display:block;
              float:left;
            }
            #linkDiv{
                border-style:solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="linkDiv">
            <a href="">test</a>
            <a href="">test</a>
            <a href="">test</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want my links to be blocks and also each of them to be next to the other. Without `float:left` this is what I get:

[image]

However when I use `float:left` this is the result:

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "clearfix" on the parent element:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Or

```
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
overflow: auto
```

on the containing `div`

or use a clearfix hack.

Answer (score 0):

You could put add this to your css:

```
#linkDiv {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

but why not use an inline-block on your a tags instead?

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
#linkDiv {
    border-style:solid;
}​
```

Inline-block elements look a lot like left floated elements, but behave more like regular inline elements (which can often be easier to manipulate). Works in all browsers IE8+ (and there's an easy polyfill for IE7).

A couple of articles that might be useful:

- http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/
- http://www.onderhond.com/blog/inline-block-vs-float